# Using Compass' image-url with relative_assets for stylesheets in subdirectories?

Tags: compass-sass

So my source tree looks like this:

```
assets/
├── css/
│   ├── master.css.scss
│   └── admin/
│       └── admin_master.css.scss
└── img/
    └── background.jpg
```

I have the Compass option `relative_assets` turned on and the `css_dir` and `images_dir` options set up correctly.

My problem is, that when calling `image-url("background.jpg")` from either `master.css.scss` or `admin_master.css.scss`, it always returns `"../img/background.jpg"`, which of course is right for the former, but not for the latter (where it would actually mean `"/assets/css/img/background.jpg"`).

Is there any way to override the relative paths on a file-per-file basis, in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a config / setup issue to me - I have this running fine on multiple projects and compass handles the various depths of stylesheets ok (it adds an extra ../ for the files that are 1 level deeper in the tree).

Try reviewing your compass config.rb file and check the css_dir (the folder you compile your css to, not the one where you .scss files live) and your project_path are correct.

Hope it helps,